# Akka Tcp server with idle connection functionality

Tags: akka

I want to implement tcp server with Akka.
I want to have idle connection timeout: If client doesn't send anything in some period of time - connection is closed.

How can I implement this? I didn't find any configs or messages in akka.io for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the receive timeout functionality which is built into all actors in your connection-actor:

```
context.setReceiveTimeout(10 seconds)
```

You can read more about it in the manual: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#Receive_timeout

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot